# wordpress login/register link not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I've purchased a theme called Foxin for Wordpress. I'm wanting to create a user area where they can log into the site and see their profile page with some links for only logged in used to use. I've achieved this by using the plugin called Ultimate Member. My issues is now that when I click on the login link at the top right hand, nothing happens. I've reached out to the developer but no luck on a response from them yet. I've located where the code is for that top header bar and it looks like it's supposed to work with Woocommerce (which we aren't using woocommerce for this site). What can I replace this code with to get it to just go to the login page [here](http://odysseyrehab.tdgclients.com/login)?

The main development site is:[here](http://odysseyrehab.tdgclients.com/)

```
<div class="content-inner">
    <div class="left pull-left">
      <?php get_template_part( 'templates/parts/socials' ); ?>
    </div>  

     <div class="right pull-right">
        <div class="topbar-meta">
          <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
            <div class="menu-my-account">
              <a title="<?php esc_html_e('My Account','foxin'); ?>"><i class="gv-icon-380"></i><?php esc_html_e('My Account','foxin'); ?></a>
              <div class="content-inner">
              <?php echo do_action( 'foxin_my_account_menu' ); ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          <?php }else { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ); ?>" title="<?php esc_html_e('Login / Register','foxin'); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Login / Register','foxin'); ?></a>
         <?php } ?>
        </div>
     </div>   
  </div>
```

I assume the bit that I really need to change out is this bit? I'm not THAT great with PHP and would like some direction on which direction I need to take this.

```
<?php echo do_action( 'foxin_my_account_menu' ); ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          <?php }else { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ); ?>" title="<?php esc_html_e('Login / Register','foxin'); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Login / Register','foxin'); ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured a way to make it work. Does this all look PROPER?

I did the following:

```
<div class="right pull-right">
        <div class="topbar-meta">
          <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
            <div class="menu-my-account">
              <a href="http://odysseyrehab.tdgclients.com/login/" title="<?php esc_html_e('My Account','foxin'); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('My Account','foxin'); ?></a>          
            </div>
          <?php }else { ?>
            <a href="http://odysseyrehab.tdgclients.com/login/" title="<?php esc_html_e('Login / Register','foxin'); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Login / Register','foxin'); ?></a>
         <?php } ?>
        </div>
     </div>   
  </div>
```